# SQL - result in one record

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL (first time) and I try to get my result in 1 record:

I have a table with 3 entries: city_name, company_name, and employee number

Basically, in my table I have a company which repeats 2 times: city_name: Rome, company_name: ABC, employee number: 100 --> this entry is 2 times in the table

How can I make this 2 entries to be shown in the table as a single record and to sum my employee numbers. I need that 2x100 empolyee to be in a single shown as 200? So I will have something like this:

```
city_name   company_name   employee
Rome        ABC            200
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results *as text tables*.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Use group by or distinct clause.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing `group by`:

```
select city_name, company_name, sum(empoyee_number)
from t
group by city_name, company_name
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I forgot to mention, I want that double entry to be shown as 1, but I need the employee number to be sum together. So just 1 record for city_name, company_name, but for employee to show 200 (100+100), 100 from each of the previous record. Thank you